# Why do New relic stopped daemons when resizing azure server?

Tags: monitoring, azure

When resizing an Azure Resource Manager server everything went well except that the application and server daemons stopped.

Stating the application daemon was easy enough but the `newrelic-sysmond` failed to start.

So I had to reinstall it. Unfortunately I don't have any log entries.

Why does this happen?

Comment: this seems to be an unexpected behavior and not a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have't 50 reputation to add a comment.

Different VM sizes require different physical hardware, when you resizing your VM, the VM need a reboot. After the VM was started, the services which startup type are automatic will start, and startup type are manual will stop. So we need to check the application daemon’s startup type, also we need check the service dependencies.

I had test this many times in my lab, but the newrelic-sysmond can start. It seems not a common issue.
Hope this helps you.

Best Regards,